# unable to access parms in expressjs router.delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Here is my Snippet of Code, Where I used Express router and Mongoose Model .

I'm Unable to Access id parm .

```js
router.delete('/task/:id', function (req, res) {
    Task.remove({ did: req.parms.id }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);

        }
    });


});
```

This is the Error I received

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at F:\NS\routes\tasks.js:11:33
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>       at param (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)
>       at param (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
>       at Function.process_params (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
>       at next (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>       at Function.handle (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
>       at router (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>       at F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
>       at Function.process_params (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>       at next (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>       at F:\NS\node_modules\express-validator\lib\express_validator.js:291:5
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
>       at F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
>       at Function.process_params (F:\NS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object isn't `parms` when accessing a route parameter, its [`params`.](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) Since `parms` is always going to be `undefined` you're going to have this issue because you're trying to access a property of `undefined` which you can't do.

```
router.delete('/task/:id', (req, res) => {
    Task.remove({ did: req.params.id }, (err) => {
        if (err) 
            return res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you will probably see this when you run the code but, Model.remove() is deprecated. Instead, I recommend Model.[deleteOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/) in the case in a future update it is no longer supported.